# Using the tufte-book class along with babelbib in French

Tags: babel, tufte

I am working on a French document using the tufte-book class and I get errors related to the bibliography.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[french]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Example of a French sidenote reference \cite{example}.

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{babplain}

\end{document}
```

The content of `references.bib` is :

```
@techreport{example,
title = {Exemple d'un rapport technique avec un accent},
language = {french},
year = {2000},
author = {Tremblay, Jean},
pages = {1--10},
institution = {Institut de recherche du Québec}
}
```

I get the following error:

`Undefined control sequence. l.2 \providebibliographyfont {name}{}%`

The error doesn't occur if I comment the call to the `babelbib` package and change the bibliography style to plain. Nonetheless, this produces a sidenote refrence with improper encoding:

[image]

Plus I get the "Technical Report" label instead of "Rapport technique" (French).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `nobib` option (on which the documentation is silent), which disables the loading of `natbib` (which in turn would disable `babelbib`).

```
\documentclass[french,nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Example of a French sidenote reference \cite{example}.

\bibliographystyle{babplain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is “rapport technique“ lower case? It seems a problem in `babelbib`. You can fix it, though.

```
\documentclass[french,nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  % \bibsfrench has 'rapport technique'
  \xpatchcmd{\bibsfrench}{rapport}{Rapport}{}{}%
}

\begin{document}
Example of a French sidenote reference \cite{example}.

\bibliographystyle{babplain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem because adding the "nobib" option results in no sidenote reference being printed...

Comment: @cathenkayak Sorry, that's how far you can go, as the class needs `bibentry` which seems to depend on `natbib`. The `tufte` classes are badly written, in my opinion.

Comment: @cathenkayak Actually, `bibentry` doesn't really depend on `natbib`, but apparently the way `bibplain` writes the `.bbl` file conflicts with `bibentry`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the \bibliographystyle{plain-fr} without use add the nobib option. It's seems to work.